# proportional image resizing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm trying try to show a couple of images at 65% of their original size using this CSS rule:

```
div#midline .artistEntry img {
    height: 65%;
    width: 65%;
}
```

It seems to work fine in IE and Firefox

[image]

But in Chrome it looks terrible. It seems that the width of the image has been correctly reduced, but the height has actually been expanded.

[image]

Is there a way to proportionally resize an image using CSS that works in all modern browsers? If not, I'd (relucantly) consider a JavaScript/jQuery solution

Comment: Try setting the width property only.

Comment: @hunter - because he asks really hard questions =). Don, in Chrome the 65% height appears to be that of the container as opposed to the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#midline .artistEntry img {
    height : auto;
    width  : 65%;
}
```

Setting one of the dimensions to `auto` (which is the default) should keep the aspect ratio intact while stretching the other dimension to a percent of it's parents dimension.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mu6h7/ (re-size the preview panel to see the aspect ratio stay intact)

Answer (score 0):

remove the height or width rule. By defining height and width, it will grab both of those, if you remove one it will scale correctly.